# Mapping Excel columns with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently mapping column names to variables in excel and then using the variables in my formula for new rows, here is an example example;

```
Dim posType as String

Cells.Find(What:="PositionType", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
    :=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
    False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate


posType = ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Address(False, False)
posType = Left(posType, InStr(1, posType, ":") - 1)


Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1").Select

ActiveCell.End(xlToRight).Select

ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "PTH Size"

 ' PTH SIZE
Cells.Find(What:="PTH SIZE", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
    :=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
    False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

Selection.Formula = _
  "=IF(" & posType & "2=""PTH""," & settlementDateQuantity & "2,0)"

pthSize = ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Address(False, False)
pthSize = Left(pthSize, InStr(1, pthSize, ":") - 1)
r = ActiveCell.Row

With Worksheets("sheet1").Range(pthSize & r)
    .AutoFill Destination:=Range(pthSize & r & ":" & pthSize & lastrow&)
End With
```

The file I import can change from day to day in the order of their columns but they allays use the same names, currently I am using the find method to get the column then saving the letter to a string and using the reference in my formula however the process of using find and mapping 100 columns is pretty slow...

I have been trying to come up with a better method to do this but cant think of anything faster, could anyone help me out by suggesting a possibly faster way of doing this?

I am also considering moving my project across to EXCEL DNA, does anyone know how much faster it would make my macros run?

Thanks

Comment: Are you setting `Application.ScreenUpdating` to false before you start your mapping? Doing so can really speed things up. Apart from that I have no suggestion, though :-(

Comment: Yea and calculations are off :( thanks anyway.

Comment: Are the columns always in a continuous range like A:D and not A:D and G:I?  If so you could probably put the range into a dictionary and search that instead.

Comment: I so I have a dynamic range and I am now searching that which has sped things up slightly. I suppose this is the only way of doing it.

Comment: I have found that a consistent data input helps to remove some of the needed search functionality. I typically sort my worksheets into a standard order then execute other code. Is this along the lines of what you are looking for? If so I can post some code.

Comment: Yes Desert thats the right idea, the only problem is sometimes we may need to add a new column to the data we receive and this throws out all the formula and the only way around that is what I posted above, I suppose the only answer would be to get consistency in the file.

Comment: Please avoid selecting cells; this is slow and unnecessary.

Comment: You say addition of a new column is infrequent. I would have a hidden worksheet with a list of column headers plus anything else I wanted to know about columns. I would load the hidden worksheet and the top row of the target worksheet to arrays using `Variant = Range.Value`. A tight loop will check the two arrays were in the same sequence. Only if they are not in the same sequence will you need to breakout, determine the new sequence and rebuild the hidden worksheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are selecting and moving around a workbook rather than just doing the assignments this will slow down the program A LOT!!!

I made **SOME** changes to move you in the right direction - Try this out:
(NOTE: It was quick and dirty, so I may have made a few mistakes in cell references, but it should move you in a better direction at the very least)

```
  Dim posType As String
  Dim SelectedCell As Range

  Set SelectedCell = Cells.Find(What:="PositionType", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
      :=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
      False, SearchFormat:=False)

  posType = Mid(SelectedCell.Address, 2, InStr(2, SelectedCell.Address, "$") - 2)

  Set SelectedCell = Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1)
  SelectedCell.Value = "PTH Size"

   ' PTH SIZE
  Set SelectedCell = Cells.Find(What:="PTH SIZE", After:=SelectedCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
  LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
      False, SearchFormat:=False).Offset(1, 0)

  SelectedCell.Formula = "=IF(" & posType & "2=""PTH""," & settlementDateQuantity & "2,0)"


  pthSize = Mid(SelectedCell.Address, 2, InStr(2, SelectedCell.Address, "$") - 2)
  r = SelectedCell.Row

  Worksheets("sheet1").Range(pthSize & r).AutoFill Destination:=Range(pthSize & r & ":" & pthSize & lastrow&)
```

Again, note that this could still be made substantially more efficient, but this is a much more efficient way of doing things...

Comment: Great, This has sped things up a bit, any other suggestions are appreciated, I understand the method of not actual moving around the workbook, so im going to work on that.